# How am I able to send data from a select and input field using ngFor?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, ngfor

I have a ngFor that loops through a REST service and displays the data in a select field.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let d of data.listCustomFields;">
            <div class="g-col-12 g-col-md-2">
              <label id="{{ d.name }}" class="col-form-label">{{ d.name }}:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="g-col-12 g-col-md-4" formGroupName="listCustomFields">
              <select id="dropdown" name="{{ d.fieldId }}" class="form-select" formControlName="listItems"  >
                <option disabled selected value>Select</option>
                <option *ngFor="let x of d.listItems" [value]="x" >{{x}}</option>
              </select>
            </div>
        </ng-container>
```

In the UI the fields display correctly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiNd0.jpg)

When I select two options only one shows in my response.

```
{ "listItems": "TEST" }
```

How do I get more than one option to show in my response?

Comment: listItems is only one item. Pass an array

```
{ "listItems": [ "Test1", "Test2" ] } 
```

Comment: @Den Is it possible to see an example?  Thanks

Comment: Can you create an example in stackblitz? Then i try to "correct"

Comment: As @Den said, you use listItems as a single control for all dropdowns, so it gets updated/changed to any value you select in any dropdown. You can make your form dynamic by having each element of listCustomFields with an id or some unique property, so that you can build a form with controls named after id; and your formControlName could be like `[formControlName]="d.id"`. However, it all depends on actual code you have and the structure of data you're iterating over.